# I have table that i use to update mysql via ajax or jquery and works for firefox,opera,chrome and safari but not IE8

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, internet-explorer-8

First off im real new to this and im sure ill use some jargon incorrectly but hopefully youll understand what i mean.
Okay i have an HTML table with a set of numbers that gets incremented when you click them then sent to the database. 
ive been using either this line

```
$.get('character/statincrease/stat/'+statname);
```

or this line

```
sendAjaxRequest('http://www.myfakeurl.com/character/statincrease/stat/'+statname);
```

in order to send the updated variable to a php handler which in turn updates the mysql database.
either line will work flawlessly with mac machine w/ chrome,firefox,safari,and opera
and also windows7 machine with chrome but when using the same win7 machine with IE8 the DB is not updated. For the longest i tried a lot of different variations of code for the ajax request and for my variables and nothing has worked. The whole time i was thinking that perhaps IE8 was ignoring the request or somehow parsing the variables in a way the server wasnt understanding however by using fiddler i was able to see that the http request was indeed being executed using IE8. In fact it is getting back a 200 response in both IE8 and chrome however When using IE8 the only difference i could spot was that when using chrome there was an additional client request header that reads

```
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

and Accept-Language reads with the additional charaacters

```
en-us,en;q=0.8
```

as oppsed to IE8

```
en-us
```

the responses from the servers were different as well
the one when using chrome had a content length of 4568 and content type of

```
text/html;charset=utf-8
```

and it looks like a good html page in text view

the response when using IE8 was only 263 long and type was

```
text/html
```

it was a small javascript that gave a top.location.href=

My mysql DB is set to utf-8

so im thinking that my php handler is really not setup to take in some href from javascript but handles the html fine thereby it updates the DB?

so could this be what is making the request not update the database in IE8?
what is the default charset for http requests in IE8?
Can i change  my code by inserting a header into the request somehow to make IE8 send it in utf-8? if so how would i modify the xmlhttprequest to do so?
Am i totally barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: what is "statname", does is contain chars that have to be encoded?

Comment: staname=HP or MP whatever is selected

Comment: so the request ends up being /character/statincrease/stat/HP

Comment: so the response in IE is something like  "top.location.href= " ? Do you have any file on the server that may output this response?

Comment: so after some more searching ive read that IE8 can have problems with cross-domain xmlhttprequests, since this is iframed into another site could it be a cross domain issue that is causing the server to respond with a top.loation.href tag to the site its iframed in?

Comment: okay so now ive tried from the same page just adding a button that has the href value http://www.myfakeurl.com/character/statincrease/stat/HP

Comment: the button works and updates the database so the request works fine so long as it is not a xmlhttprequest or jquery get  so there is some clue to my problem, it is only IE8 and it is only when the request is an ajax request hmmm im stumped?

Comment: So is this a cross-domain-request or not? Can you please post all response-headers?

Comment: i thought perhaps it was seeing it as a cross domain but it is not. what im looking into now is that perhaps when using the button to redirect it works because IE8 doesnt cache but when using the ajax request IE8 just caches it ill try and get the headers when im back on the windows machine again tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

some friends helped me resolve this issue, unfortunatley the solution is a little over my head to explain but it had something to do with my page being iframed in a page that required a login and even though the function wasnt relying on cookies something to do with IE seeing the cookies that were sent as third party caused IE to invalidate the login session on the upper site